# when returning data to `.ajax` callback in jquery, do I have to user `echo`?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, callback, echo

I'm a n00b learning via online tutorial.  I have the following code in a "server side" test file called "response.php":

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST))
{
$answer = $_POST;
echo json_encode($answer);
}  else {
echo json_encode(array('status' => false, 'msg' => 'no good'));
}  
?>
```

Do I always have to use `echo` when returning data to an `.ajax` jquery callback?  Are there other ways to send the data back to the client?

Comment: You have to return the text to the browser. You can use any method that accomplishes that.

Comment: returning data to a web-based client **IS** output. unless you plant to send data via http headers or status codes, echo/print is the only way you can send stuff back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, otherwise you are just calling `json_encode` and discarding the result.

`json_encode` just *returns* the encoded string. You then have to send it back to the browser with `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

u can also use print :) other than echo .